# Assignment stuck in reading files in to classes

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

```
    public static Course getCourse (Scanner scan) throws Exception{

    Course crs = new Course();

    crs.course_id= scan.next();
    crs.course_name = scan.next();
    crs.lecture_id = scan.next();
    crs.instructor_id = scan.next();
    crs.instructor_name = scan.next();


    return crs;


}
```

this is my code that's probleming me.

the values int the code are strings.

```
getCourse(Scanner scan)
```

returns the class

and it is supposed to save to a Course[] list array.

I input a data file by doing this in unix

```
java Main <data
```

it gets the line data

```
public CourseManage(Scanner scanner){

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        numCourses++;
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    courses = new Course[numCourses];

}
```

like this well. The file is 5 lines and it returns 5 lines well.

but the code above will return me null errors.

well it was

```
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        crs.course_id= scan.next();
        crs.course_name = scan.next();
        crs.lecture_id = scan.next();
        crs.instructor_id = scan.next();
        crs.instructor_name = scan.next();
        scan.nextLine();
    }
```

first when i made the codes,

it doesn't print null errors

but instead, when i try to print the string values, they return null values

is the Static making all the mess?

should i take it off?

Comment: what are the data types of attributes of class Course?

Comment: Please show us your complete code and an example of your file, so we can rebuild your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the Static making all the mess?

No.

> should i take it off?

No.

Your question is really hard to understand, and you are only providing code snippets.  However, I suspect that the problem is that your `CourseManage` constructor is reading all of the input data in order to find out how big to make the array.  When you then get to call `getCourse`, the scanner is at the "end-of-file" position, and (naturally) that means it can't read anything.

There are a number of ways to solve this, but the cleanest way is to hold the `Course` objects in a `List<Course>` rather than a `Course[]`.  That way you won't need to pre-read the stream to figure out how big the array needs to be.

Comment: *"that means it can't read anything."* OP said his values are `null`. Scanner never "reads" null, it would throw an Exception instead.

Comment: @Tom - I noted that.  I'd assumed that the OP was not expressing himself clearly.  For once in my life, I resisted the urge to be a pedant :-)